# Debugging a prisoner's simulation

Tags: python

[Prisoner's Dilemma](http://pastie.org/private/uma67ccauc2xhjeravlvna)

This program should return 204 and 199, but instead returns 0 and 1000.
I can fix the problem by changing the first and second lines of the main method to:

```
    FirstStrat = Defector()
    SecondStrat = TitForTat()
```

Why might this be happening?

How could I change the program so that it works no matter the order I enter `Defector` and `TitForTat` in?

Comment: I know what the problem is, but I have no idea why it happens, so someone else may enlighten us both.

Comment: Problem comes with the inheritance. Both `TitForTat` and `Defector` seem to be sharing the resources from `Strategy`. In other words, they are calling the same `update` method which modifies the same `self.opponent_moves`, so `self.opponent_moves` does not have the opponent moves, it has the moves from both players, rendering the method `get_move` from `TitForTat` to always get the move from the `SecondStrat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you defined the variables from the class `Strategy`. By defining them this way:

```
class Strategy(object):
    turn_number = 1
    moves = []
    opponent_moves = []
    total_points = 0
    opponent_points = 0
```

All those variables will be shared by all instances of the class `Strategy` (or any of it's subclasses). This makes it so that `self.opponent_moves` will not save the moves from the opponent, it will save the moves from both players (since they share this variable when each calls the method `update`), therefore the method `get_move` from `TitForTat` will return the last move from the `SecondStrat` instead of the last move from the opponent.

To solve your problem, just define them as class variables inside the `__init__`:

```
class Strategy(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.turn_number = 1
        self.moves = []
        self.opponent_moves = []
        self.total_points = 0
        self.opponent_points = 0
```

And it will work just fine.